# What is the implementation of std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have read [std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_nothrow_copy_constructible/), and learn that we can use this function to check if a copy constructor throw or not.  And I wrote some demo as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { };
struct B { B(const B&){} };
struct C { C(const C&) noexcept {} };
struct D { int a;};
struct E { std::string a;};
struct F { F(const F&)= default; };
struct G { std::string a; G(const G&)= default; };

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "is_nothrow_copy_constructible:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int: " << std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A: " << std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<A>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B: " << std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<B>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C: " << std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<C>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "D: " << std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<D>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "E: " << std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<E>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "F: " << std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<F>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "G: " << std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<G>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And result is:

```
is_nothrow_copy_constructible:
int: true
A: true
B: false
C: true
D: true
E: false
F: true
G: false
```

I want to know why E is throw but d is not.  I guess:

1. If a custom copy constructor is declared noexcept, then std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible will suppose it to be nothrow, otherwise it will be throw.
2. If a class contains some data members whose copy constructor may throw, then the class's default copy constructor is throwable, such as class E.

I don't know if my guess is true or not.  Ant I want to know where I can find the implementation of `std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible`?

Comment: better reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible

Comment: @bolov I have read it too, but feel no help.

Comment: what is "unhelpful"? They give a very strict definition plus possible implementation.

Comment: @bolov  It's helpful in some way.  But what I need is the code implementation, neither the strict definition nor possible implementation (which is not complete).

Comment: You have the code implementation. The "possible implementation" is the code implementation. And is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's have a look at the stdlibc++ implementation of the standard library (can be found in `<type_traits>`):

```
  template<typename _Tp, typename... _Args>
    struct __is_nt_constructible_impl
    : public integral_constant<bool, noexcept(_Tp(declval<_Args>()...))>
    { };

  template<typename _Tp, typename _Arg>
    struct __is_nt_constructible_impl<_Tp, _Arg>
    : public integral_constant<bool,
                               noexcept(static_cast<_Tp>(declval<_Arg>()))>
    { };
```

The implementation just checks whether a call to a (copy-)constructor is `noexcept` (by using the [`noexcept` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept)) and inherits accordingly from a `true_type` or a `false_type`. Your assumptions are correct, the compiler is smart enough to make default constructors noexcept whenever possible, i.e., it doesn't have to call constructors of member objects not marked `noexcept`.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Although not completely understood, but you have specified the direction of learning

Comment: It's hard to understand the code in `<type_traits>`.  Can you give me some  suggest or can you tell me any book which has a explanation about stdlibc++ implementation.  Thanks again!

Comment: @selfboot There is no book on the implementation. You basically have to learn about the basics of templates and metaprogramming. Read about template specializations and SFINAE, then you will understand the code properly.